# Expected number of children for equal gender ratio

Tags: probability, expected-value

A couple has children until they have an equal number of boys and girls. Assuming P(Boy) = P(Girl) = 1/2, what is the expected number of children the couple will have?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: it is a geometric distribution with $p = \frac{1}{2}$. Do you know to calculate the expectation?

Comment: I don’t think Daniel’s comment is useful. You’re looking for the expected return time of a random walk. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.04800.pdf).

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure we were looking at a random walk hitting times @karl. The paper looks quite dense for this though.